# Rails 4: Joins with has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many

I have 2 models, `weekly_report` and `consult_stat` and they are organized as such:

```
class ConsultStat < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :weekly_report
end

class WeeklyReport < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :consult_stats
end
```

An attribute on my consult_stats table is `:consults` and I want to retrieve the **total number of consults for a given set of weekly reports**.

If I'm dealing with 1 weekly_report, I can do

```
WeeklyReport.find(x).consult_stats.sum(:consults)
```

however when I try to select a group of weekly_reports:

```
WeeklyReport.where("start_date > ?", "2016-11-01")
```

and retrieve the consult sum for their consult_stats using `joins` I keep getting an error.

Comment: what is the error? could be that your date is not formatted?

Answer (score 0):

Thats to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116122/query-records-through-its-belongs-to-relation-in-rails) I realized that

- weekly_report is singular in joins(:weekly_report) because it's a belongs_to relationship
- weekly_reports is plural in where because it's the table name

making my query:

```
ConsultStat.joins(:weekly_report).where("weekly_reports.start_date > ?", "2016-11-01")
```