# What is the most efficient way to obtain collection of ActiveRecord objects through a has_many relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Catalog model:

```
has_many :categories, dependent: :destroy
has_many :docs, through: :categories
```

Doc model:

```
belongs_to :category
```

My goal is to obtain a collection of all Doc objects that meet my query, but only those docs that are in a catalog that the user is authorized for via [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit).

I currently have:

```
catalogs = Pundit.policy_scope(user, Catalog) #get only catalogs I'm authorized for
docs = []
catalogs.each do |catalog|
  catalog.docs.where(["title like ?", query]).each do |doc|
    docs.push doc
  end
end
```

This returns the records I want, but seems inefficient to me, and I would prefer to have an ActiveRecord collection rather than an array. Is there a way to obtain these records more directly? I initially tried something like:

```
docs = Pundit.policy_scope(user, Catalog).docs
```

But that didn't work. Couldn't find a method named `docs` on the collection. Seems like normally [you could use some kind of join for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116122/query-records-through-its-belongs-to-relation-in-rails), but I can't figure out how to make this work using Pundit to filter the catalog.

Using meagar's suggestions, I've come up with this:

```
category_ids = Pundit.policy_scope(user, Catalog).joins(:categories).flat_map(&:category_ids)
docs = Doc.where(category_id: category_ids).where(['title like ?', query])
```

Which works. Is this as efficient as I can go? Is there a more "Railsy" way to do this?

Comment: Knowing nothing else about Pundit, your loop could be written: `docs = catalog.docs.where(["title like ?", query]).flat_map(&:docs)`.  That said, what you're after is a `join` or an `includes`, but I don't know if Pundit's `policy_scope` returns something like an ActiveRecord association on which you can `join` things.

Comment: Regardless, you can still turn your list of catalogs into a list of category IDs and perform the lookup of all documents in a single query: `cat_ids = catalogs.where('title like ?', query).pluck(:id); documents = Document.where(catalog_id: cat_ids)`.